# Search Postgres JSONB fields

Tags: postgresql

I want to search the pattern '%myvalue%' in key and value for a json field, return any one that matched.

I use

```
select * from dialogue_responses where field_rule like '%myvalue%'
```

it prompts me error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ~~ unknown
LINE 1: select * from dialogue_responses where field_rule like '%auf...
                                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What's he correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast into text in the query. Such as

`select * from dialogue_responses where field_rule::varchar like '%myvalue%'`

Comment: @VaoTsun: I really didn't this case is answered before. I've just answer base on my experience. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I sent you the link with opinion regarding text vs varchar. its not other answer. I upvoted your answer because this is the easiest way to find match in both keys or values in json. I just was surprised you cast jsonb to varchar, not text.